# CSS Show rounded labels

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to show rounded label at top right corner of a panel. I'm using Bootstrap3 panels and labels to achieve this. Obviously this label is not a image.

However I can't think of a clean way as I'm very poor at designing. Can anyone please give me a solution? Thanks in advance.

[image]

**Updated**
Actually my problem is not related with adding rounded borners. I want to place it in the correct position. I'm very sorry for making things confused.

Comment: Please show us the code that you have tried so far. This is relatively easy to achieve by adding `border-radius` to a `div` and positioning it near the top right of the panel.

Comment: for labels use `position:absolute` so you can move them to right. Keep in mind you use `position:relative` for `parent` element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use border-radius property http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

```css
.index {
    border-radius: 50%
    // ...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/243kwbjf/1/

Answer (score 3):

You could use [border-radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) property.

For circles use value `border-radius: 50%;`.

Answer (score 2):

Apply `border-radius:50%;` to respected elements.

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.index {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0063ff;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="image" />
  <span class="index">1</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="image" />
  <span class="index">2</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="image" />
  <span class="index">3</span>
</div>
```